# Is there a Java equivalent for C#'s HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode?

Tags: java, c#, android, url-encoding

How do I encode in Java a string that is going to get decoded in C# using `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode`?

Comment: the above link is for decoding in Java, but i need encoding in Java. so that i could decode it in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method replicates the C# functionality.

```java
public static String urlTokenEncode(String inputString) {
    if (inputString == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (inputString.length() < 1) {
        return null;
    }

    // Step 1: Do a Base64 encoding
    String base64Str = new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(inputString.getBytes()));

    // Step 2: Transform the "+" to "-", and "/" to "_"
    base64Str = base64Str.replace('+', '-').replace('/', '_');

    // Step 3: Find how many padding chars are present at the end
    int endPos = base64Str.lastIndexOf('=');
    char paddingChars = (char)((int)'0' + base64Str.length() - endPos);

    // Step 4: Replace padding chars with count of padding chars
    char[] base64StrChars = base64Str.toCharArray();
    base64StrChars[endPos] = paddingChars;

    return new String(base64StrChars);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a day struggling, this simple method did the work:

```
public string ToUnsafeUrl(this string str)
    {
        if (str == null)
            return null;
        return str.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/");
    }
```